# Replace a null in a char with letter using a function?

Tags: c, function, null

So I'm having trouble replacing a char variable which I set to null with a letter using a function. Inside my function, the variable is able to be changed, but in the main function it stays as a null, so I am not sure what I am doing.

The code I wrote is basically like

```
int main(){

    char a='\0';

    somefunction(a);
return 0;
}
```

with the function being

```
somefunction(char a){

scanf(" %c",&a);
}
```

So if I input B, the a value in the function would be B, but the a value in main would stay as \0.

Comment: C is pass by value.  The function cannot change the variable in the caller.  You need to pass the address of the variable to the function if you want the function to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

a is being changed only in a local context, since you're passing the value of a and it's being changed locally.

To fix this, you need to change the signature so you can change the value of a in a greater context (ie the calling function.

Try something like

```
somefunction(char *a) {
    scanf("%c",a);
}
```

And now you pass the address of a (ie `&a` instead of a), and it should work.

Comment: Removing the leading space in `" %c"` to `"%c"` will likely create problems for OP.

Comment: You must forgive me, can you elaborate at all?

Answer (score 1):

In C, variables are passed by *value*, not by *reference* (unless you specify otherwise). That is, the program is passing the value `'\0'` to your function, not any reference to the variable `a`.

If you want to affect the variable itself, you need to use a *pointer*.

```
void somefunction(char *a){
    *a = 'Q';
}

int main(){
    char a = '\0';
    somefunction(&a);
    printf("'%c'", a); /* Prints 'Q' */
}
```

Note that you've already done this once in your example, when you pass a pointer to `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

With `scanf(" %c",&a);` code gives the address of `a` to `scanf()` so `scanf()` can assign something at that address.

Do the same with `somefunction();`, give it an address.

```
// somefunction(char a){
void somefunction(char *a) {
  // scanf(" %c",&a);
  scanf(" %c", a);
}

int main() {
    char a = '\0';
    // somefunction(a);
    somefunction(&a);
    printf("<%c>\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `somefunction`, your program creates a new copy of `a` on the stack. You're passing the address of that copy of `a` to `scanf`. When your function returns, the original `a` in main is unchanged.

You need to make `somefunction` take a pointer to main's copy of `a`, then pass that pointer directly to `scanf`.

```
somefunction(char *a) {
    scanf(" %c", a);
}

char a;
somefunction(&a);
```